# Why is my Apollo Client optimistic reply failing?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm recording this to document the answer to a problem that took me several hours to solve. Scenario:

I'm using two mutation queries on a single component in React Apollo-Client. This is a component wrapped into a larger component to form a page. Something like this (this is not the actual code, but it should give the idea):

```
import { compose } from 'react-apollo';

// submitNewUser contains
//  postedBy
//  createdAt
//  content

// submitRepository contains
//  otherProp

const thisProps1 = {
  name: 'mutation1',
  props: ({ ownProps, mutation1 }) => ({
    submit: ({ repoFullName, commentContent }) => mutation1({
      variables: { repoFullName, commentContent },
      optimisticResponse: {
        __typename: 'Mutation',
        submitNewUser: {
          __typename: 'Comment',
          postedBy: ownProps.currentUser,
          content: commentContent,
        },
      },
    }),
  }),
};
const thisProps2 = {
  name: 'mutation2',
  props: ({ ownProps, mutation2 }) => ({
    submit: ({ repoFullName, commentContent }) => mutation2({
      variables: { repoFullName, commentContent },
      optimisticResponse: {
        __typename: 'Mutation',
        submitRepository: {
          __typename: 'Comment',
          otherProp: 'foobar',
        },
      },
    }),
  }),
};
const ComponentWithMutations = compose(
  graphql(submitNewUser, thisProps1),
  graphql(submitRepository, thisProps2)
)(Component);
```

Whenever the optimistic response fires, only the second result is fed back to into the query-response in the outer component. In other words, the first query gives an 'undefined' response (but no error), while the second returns an object as expect.

Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property "createdAt" is not included in the optimistic reply.

```
__typename: 'Comment',
postedBy: ownProps.currentUser,
content: commentContent,
```

Should be:

```
__typename: 'Comment',
postedBy: ownProps.currentUser,
createdAt: Date(),
content: commentContent,
```

**A missing field in an optimistic reply will silently fail to return anything to any queries that call that data.**